# Modelling how test agreement varies as a function of a covariate

Tags: multilevel-analysis, agreement-statistics, intraclass-correlation

I have a group of human subjects who have been given two versions of a test measuring the same outcome. I am interested in the agreement between these two tests, and whether their agreement varies as a function of subject age.

My first thought is to use a multilevel model with test scores nested within subjects, and calculate the ICC from the variance components. Then I could put in an indicator variable for the test version to see if there is a difference in mean scores; and an interaction with age to see if any differences in mean scores between the two tests vary as a function of age.

I was also hoping to see if the ICC varies by age, and this is where I get stuck.
Do I (can I?) model level 1 variance as a function of age? If I could, does this even match up with my goal of understanding if the test agreement varies with age?

Perhaps I am over-complicating things and should just calculate a difference in test scores for each person and model that as a function of age, and allow that model to have heteroskedastic error variances across ages.

Many thanks for any nudges in the right direction, preferably with lme4 or nlme in R (or maybe rstan).

Comment: I think the approach you outline in the second paragraph makes a lot of sense. You can indeed model the level 1 variance as a function of age using nlme (see link), but I do not believe this will allow you to calculate ICCs for each age group. How many age groups are there? You might consider modeling age as a random intercept in a non-nested model. https://quantdev.ssri.psu.edu/sites/qdev/files/ILD_Ch06_2017_MLMwithHeterogeneousVariance.html

Comment: Thanks Erik, that's a very useful link.